# What size wire for a 50amp rv receptacle from 200amp breaker box 50feet from breaker box

Tags: electrical

What size wire do I use to run a 50amp rv receptical 50 feet from a 200 amp breaker box

Comment: Is this run going to be exposed, underground, overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, UF 6/3. I'm assuming part of the run is outside.